# Problem in 'talking to a lot of people'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammatical-number, american-english

I told my friend that "I am talking to a lot of people" and he said this sentence is not correct. Can anyone help me find out what's wrong with the following sentence:
"Talking to a lot of people"

Comment: No. We cannot. There is nothing wrong with the sentence. **Ask your friend**. He knew exactly what his imaginary problem was, and he was right there available for comment. So why did you not ask him? Why did you instead wait to ask a random bunch of strangers off the Internet? It makes no sense at all. **Ask your friend**. Then tell him he is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is fine, the meaning clear. It could perhaps be reworded to 
*I am talking with many people*, to make it sound like more of a conversation than a speech.

Comment: Should it be 'Talking to lot of people?' instead of 'Talking to A lot of people' ?

Comment: No, "talking to **a** lot of people is correct, common and colloquial.  "Talking to lot of people" is incorrect, infinitesimally rare, and not colloqial.  (by the way, _many people_ is a bit more formal than _a lot of people_, not more "conversational")